# Can $GLOBALS be used as a store for information?

Tags: php

I am creating an api for my application in php and i want to store every connected client ip address associated to his/her username. And i don't want to create a new database or table for this process so can i just save those info into the `$GLOBALS` array ? will it persist the information i save into it ?

Psuedo Code:

```
if (!array_key_exists("banaaanaa", $GLOBALS)) {
    array_push($GLOBALS, "banaaanaa", time());
} else {
    $GLOBALS['banaaanaa'] = "new ip";
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @Phil it actually worked for me for a glance but i realized now that it isn't persistent... so any better ideas ?

Comment: @Phil is there a way to create a global static array ? that will persist the data in it ?

Comment: Hi I would suggest using the Database for this, also You won't be able to reliably know if someone is logged off unless they log out, The only real way to know is either run an ajax call for every page, or if its for only logged in users, you could keep track of the current session an check that way, it depends on how accurate you want to be, The best bet is to move the sessions to a database storage and do both, you can read this for more info http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Is there anyway i can create a global static array ? (that persist the data).

Comment: Short of memcache or similar, no, not one that will persist between users, as I and others mentioned you have to use file, database, or memcache

Comment: @DanielEugen how you define "persist", for how long ? is it request based or user based  persistence. If user based persistence, information can be retrieved later. If request based persistence, it lasts only for that request. If you clear on this then better solution can be suggested.

Comment: @codepiper persist as when multiple requests are made i can check that array and see if the user is already there and update his ip to the new one and if not just add him to the array and so on (so the data is not saved for a single user)... excuse me i am a c# programmer and i don't know a lot about php so i imagine things from a c# perspective.

Comment: @DanielEugen as you are implementing for API, its not a good idea to put in any global array as they are request based not user based. IMHO it would be better to save them in database or may be in kind of cache like memcache, redis (performance will be better for cache). If you have such information in db, later stage it can be used for reporting and generate reports.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

PHP initialises everything (including $GLOBALS) fresh on every request.

You'll need to use either your database, a file, a set of files, or memcached.

Sorry.

Given your requirements, suspecting you don't have more than a few hundred users at most, I'd probably use a directory per username, and on each logged in request touch a file with that IP inside the dir, and delete it on log-out.  You can thee easily see a list of all logged in IPs, as well as see which IPs didn't log out, but haven't made a request in a long time by looking at the mtime of the file(s).

make sure to sanitize usernames so they can't be called "../../../etc" or something. :-)

Comment: Or session or cookies for temporary storage.

Comment: Yes, session cookies can be used for temporary storage, but in this instance, he wants to share user information (which IPs are logged in with my id) between sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save data into the `$GLOBALS` Array as it contains references to all variables which are currently defined in the global scope of the script. [See Php Manual Here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php).
`For temporary Storage, you can use Sessions or Cookies`, or Use database as permanent storage.

Comment: Sessions and / or cookies wont work as the OP need to share the data between clients.